# Appending / Merging Content Security Policy Rules

Tags: html, apache, content-security-policy

In the Apache .conf file I have de folowing code:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'"
```

In the HTML/PHP file I have the folowing code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'nonce-RANDOM' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline'">
```

The problem is that when the page is loaded it only assumes the rules from the Apache and ignores the one from the HTML file.

I could put the script-src rule in the Apache .conf file but a new nonce tag must be generated every time the page is loaded. So it must be in the HTML file.

Is there away to append or merge the two rules when the site is loaded?´

**EDIT 1 This is the error given by the browser:**

> Refused to load the script '...' because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

**EDIT 2 I tried the following things:**

In Apache:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'"
```

In the HTML/PHP file:

```
<?php $nonce = RANDOM; header("Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-$nonce' 'strict-dynamic';"); ?>
```

And now when I go to the developer page of the browser I see that the browser reconizes the two rules, but only apply the first one:

```
Response Headers:
...
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-RANDOM' 'strict-dynamic'
...
```

Comment: It could help if you used https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44640867/edit to edit/update your question and add the exact CSP error message that you’re seeing in your browser devtools console. That message will show the policy that the browser is actually applying.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I added the error log.

Comment: So yeah, as the error message indicates, the browser is applying the strict policy "default-src 'none'" given in the header and you can’t relax that with a meta element. So you must specify a policy for 'script-src' in the Content-Security-Policy value in your Apache conf. As the answer here says, it seems like for the case you describe, you need to specify a liberal "script-src 'unsafe-inline'" in the header, then specify a stricter policy in the meta element, with the nonce value.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Still doesn't work, it gives the following error: "Refused to load the script '...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-inline'"".

Comment: @sideshowbarker Should I use in the Apache "Header set", "Header merge" or "Header append"?

Comment: Try "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'" in the header value. As far as what Apache header directive to use, I guess you want "Header set" in order to make sure whatever value you set there overwrites any value that might be getting set elsewhere in some other part of the Apache config.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Didn't work. I made an edit with some changes that I tried.

Comment: What exact error message are you getting now?

Comment: @sideshowbarker The same error in EDIT 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since this wasn't answered, and I happen to be hardening my server today I'll let you know what I did to make it work. I had the same problem, so I looked into the module docs and you need to use Header **merge** not **set**. I tested, and sure enough, that's the case. I've updated the header as well to support CSP 3. 100% passes validation.

```
Header merge Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; require-trusted-types-for 'script'; style-src 'self'"
```

Restart Apache and test it - https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com